# How to install Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms NuGet package to a non SDK style project using PackageReferences?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I cleaned the NuGet cache both in VS IDE and ran `nuget locals http-cache -clear`

Trying to install the package:

**NuGet Package Manager GUI**

```
Restoring packages for C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc\DataSvc.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
  GET http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a@85ac4ba3-ae74-4586-9d21-d28a67d51f3e/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
  GET http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
  OK http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json 48ms
  NotFound http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a@85ac4ba3-ae74-4586-9d21-d28a67d51f3e/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json 54ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json 299ms
NU1603: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms 150.1404.0 depends on Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (>= 14.0.0) but Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.314.76 was resolved.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'DataSvc'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:03.9174673
========== Finished ==========
```

**NuGet Package Manager Console**

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms
Restoring packages for C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc\DataSvc.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
  GET http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a@85ac4ba3-ae74-4586-9d21-d28a67d51f3e/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
  GET http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
  OK http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json 53ms
  NotFound http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a@85ac4ba3-ae74-4586-9d21-d28a67d51f3e/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json 59ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json 191ms
Install-Package : NU1603: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms 150.1404.0 depends on Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (>= 14.0.0) 
but Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.314.76 was resolved.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebFo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'DataSvc'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebFo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.1740309
PM>
```

**Command line**

```
C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc> $env:VSToolsPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0"
C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc> $env:SolutionDir="C:\xyz\tip\"
C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc> $env:MSBuildExtensionsPath32 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild"
C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc> dotnet add package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms
Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp462B.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms' into project 'C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc\DataSvc.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc\DataSvc.csproj...
info :   CACHE http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol.webforms/index.json
info :   GET http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a@85ac4ba3-ae74-4586-9d21-d28a67d51f3e/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol.webforms/index.json
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol.webforms/index.json
info :   NotFound http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a@85ac4ba3-ae74-4586-9d21-d28a67d51f3e/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol.webforms/index.json 179ms
info :   CACHE http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
info :   GET http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a@85ac4ba3-ae74-4586-9d21-d28a67d51f3e/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json
info :   NotFound http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/854ce845-6ca2-4dae-98e0-81ffaee3f06a@85ac4ba3-ae74-4586-9d21-d28a67d51f3e/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.sqlserver.types/index.json 23ms
error: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms 150.1404.0 depends on Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (>= 14.0.0) but Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.314.76 was resolved.
info : Package 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc\DataSvc.csproj'.
info : PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms' version '150.1404.0' added to file 'C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc\DataSvc.csproj'.
info : Committing restore...
info : Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc\obj\project.assets.json
log  : Failed to restore C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc\DataSvc.csproj (in 606 ms).
C:\xyz\tip\Services\Platform\WBDataSvc\DataSvc>
```

Also of note - https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5764

What I do not understand is - this is supposed to be a warning only. Why it behaves like an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your project has some node to treat this warning as error which leads this issue.

**In our side**, it is just a nuget warning and will not preventing the installation of the package.

Please check on `xxx.csproj`, any imported `targets` or `props` files, `Directory.Build.props` or `Directory.Build.props` if you used.

**Remove** any node on those files:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
     <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
     <WarningsAsErrors>NU1603</WarningsAsErrors>
 </PropertyGroup>
```